# Inserting an increment value within a foreach statement without using an auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a foreach statement that takes PHP POST data and adds it to a mysql db similar to this:

```
    foreach ($_POST['print_dim'] as $row => $printd) {
    $print_dim = $printd;
    $method = $_POST['method'][$row];
// insert into database
}
```

This foreach updates 6 columns of data.
I need to insert values starting at 1 up to 44 along with the foreach update in incremental order without using auto_increment in mysql. Could I add to this foreach to add an incremented number with each insert or would I need to create a new query to insert the incremental numbers?  I am newer to PHP so any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I am just not sure how to write the code to insert the numbers into the database in the column I need them in.  I am sure there is an easy way to insert this into a database.

Some background is that basically I am creating a template of values based on a form for inspections.  The template saves to a couple of tables in a db and the column that I need the incremental numbers in have to be there so that when I insert this template data into another table it has to reference that line number so it does not break my application.  Unfortunately I took this app over from a former employee and I need this work around to prevent a lot more time trying to re-code everything.  Thanks for any assistance possible.

Comment: Why "*without using auto_increment in mysql*"?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you able to alter the SQL table to have an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key and then use something like lastInsertId()?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Because I need the increment to reset with each new template is added to the db, and I am already using auto_increment for the primary key.

Comment: Since you are admittedly new to php, I would recommend learning PDO immediately and using it always (or some would argue mysqli)

Comment: 80% of the app was written with the pre pdo depreciated code (pre php 5.5) before I inherited it, and I plan on fixing it all.  It's an internal LAN app.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - I just need to add 1 up to 44  as a INT to a db when each of these POSTS are added.  Could be a whole new query to UPDATE or INSERT INTO.  I just need help getting the increment data into the db, then when a user adds a new template, the process starts over with 1 up to 44.  Thanks for being so quick on these :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i=1;
foreach ($_POST['print_dim'] as $row => $printd) {
    $print_dim = $printd;
    $method = $_POST['method'][$row];
    $i++
    // INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES($i, $print_dim, $method);
}
```

Like this?

Comment: yes very similar to that but when I try that it only adds the "1" to my database and not incrementally.  But yes similar to that if possible.

Comment: This ought to increment the `id` column just fine, though as written, it will start at 2.  I would move the `$i++;` below your query (and add a semicolon).  Also, make sure to escape the other values in the insert.

Comment: No luck @SuperJer. It only increments by one. So row one is 0 which does not contain a print_dim or method, then the rest of the rows is 1 which contain template data.  It inserts the one but nothing else.  :(

Comment: I think we'll need a better look at what exactly your form, php, and SQL insert looks like, in order to determine the best way to iterate through your data.

Comment: I take back my statement about it not working, it does actually work.  I was looking at the wrong file that is similar to this one.  THANK YOU ALL for your help on this.  This is exactly what I needed.